# How to fill grouped/dodged bars with another variable in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, fill

I would like to get the same graph given by this code:

```
library(ggplot2)

name <- c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B")
size <- c("small","small","tall","tall","small","small","tall","tall")
flag <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)
quantity <- c(26,13,12,4,19,14,13,5)

df <- data.frame(name,size,flag,quantity)

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = name, y = quantity)) +
 geom_bar(aes(fill = size), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

Except that I would like to have the bars split according to the variable flag. the ideal would be to have a different shade of color for the portion of the bars that corresponds to `flag = 0`.

I also need to have a legend for the flag variable.

Comment: You could use `interaction(size, flag)` or `alpha = factor(flag)`... facets are also an option - it depends on what you mean with a different shade of color

Comment: @kath worth mentioning that `alpha = factor(flag)` works only inside `aes()`.

Comment: I provided some examples below to make more clear where these things should go ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)

df1 <- data.frame(name = c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
                  size = c("small","small","tall","tall","small","small","tall","tall"),
                  flag = c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1),
                  quantity = c(26,13,12,4,19,14,13,5))

ggplot(data = df1, mapping = aes(x = name, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = size), alpha = ifelse(flag==0, 0.6, 1),
           position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Adding on top of *@kath* answer:

```r
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)

gg_color_hue <- function(n) {
                             hues = seq(15, 375, length = n + 1)
                             hcl(h = hues, l = 65, c = 100)[1:n]
                             }

mycols <- gg_color_hue(length(unique(interaction(df$size, df$flag)))/2)


ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = interaction(name, size), y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = interaction(factor(size), factor(flag))), 
           position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(name = "Size and Flag",
                    values = c("small.0" = alpha(mycols[1], 3/5),
                               "tall.0" = alpha(mycols[2], 3/5),
                               "small.1" = alpha(mycols[1], 1),
                               "tall.1" = alpha(mycols[2], 1)),
                    labels = c("Size: small and Flag: 0",
                               "Size: tall and Flag: 0",
                               "Size: small and Flag: 1",
                               "Size: tall and Flag: 1")) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank(),
        panel.spacing = unit(-1.25, "lines")) + 
  xlab("name")
```

[image]

Comment: the problem is that the bar does not have the correct height, right? the total height of A small, for example, should be 26+13. However here it stops at 26. It is not about your code, it's about ggplot2 ignoring the second entry for "A small" (same problem when not taking into account the flag). I don't know how it can be solved?

Comment: @sargg that's easy to fix. ```library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(name, size) %>% arrange(flag) %>% mutate(quantity=cumsum(quantity)) %>% ggplot(...``` *p.s. I just wrote the code, it's not tested.*

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't really solve it as it doesn't show the "flag" info inside the same bar, but dodged . The second answer of @kath solves it though, the combination of facet_wrap and interaction.

Answer (score 2):

Using different alpha-values for the flag:
This adds different transparency values for the flag. However, all bars are dodged.

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = name, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = size, alpha = factor(flag)), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  scale_alpha_manual("flag", values = c(0.3, 1))
```

[image]

A combination of `facet_wrap` with an interaction on the x-axis (name, size):
Keeps the stacking of the bars for the same size, workaround is needed to have a nice x-axis.

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = interaction(name, size), y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = size, alpha = factor(flag)), 
           position = "stack", stat = "identity") +
  scale_alpha_manual("flag", values = c(0.3, 1)) +
  facet_wrap(~ name, strip.position = "bottom", scales = "free_x") +
  theme(axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Interaction with size:
With specifying a `scale_fill_manual` you can assign different colors to the different combinations of size and flag.

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = name, y = quantity)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = interaction(size, flag)), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]